# Android - sending email from app

Tags: android, email-attachments

I am facing problems in sending email from an Android app. It works intermittently and unreliably. Most of the times, it is stuck in Outbox, in 'Sending..' state.

I know this is a oft-repeated question here, but I am asking it again because I have tried quite a few variations in code, and none of them seem to work RELIABLY. Some forums also say that this is GMail app's fault; and I have tried 'refreshing the outbox folder' and 'disabling and enabling sync', but nothing seems to do the trick.

Here is my code:

```
Intent emailIntent = new Intent(android.content.Intent.ACTION_SEND);
emailIntent.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, "subject");
emailIntent.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, "emailText");
emailIntent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
emailIntent.setType("application/zip");
emailIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, Uri.fromFile(new File("/mnt/sdcard/myFolder/myFile.zip")));
startActivity(Intent.createChooser(emailIntent, "send email"));
finish();
```

1. Could someone explain why wouldn't this work?
2. What should be the value for setType()? Where can I find a list of available values?
3. Is it because I am trying to send a .zip file? If so, would other archive formats work?

Thanks a lot for your help.

EDIT: I suspect that the issue is with file format (.zip). Other file formats work just fine. I have abandoned this approach and gone for TCP with my own server listening for data.

Comment: On #2, have you tried others? Googling provides some other options, like application/x-compressed or multipart/x-zip

Comment: I can always write a small server and go for TCP to get data from my android app, but _why wouldn't email work?_

Answer (score 0):

The reason why it could be stuck in the sending state is because depending on the **SIZE** of the zip file, it has to add it to the email.. If its too large (over 30 MB) it might hang and get denied by google, since google does not allow the sending of over 30MB in an email. This is just a guess, but try sending a small file and see if this is the case.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. File size is considerably small, around one MB.

Comment: Try sending just sending one file like a picture or something and see if the same thing happens. If it does then it could be you have a weak connection on the phone and its not sending it.

Comment: I tried sending a .csv file, and it worked, although took some time. .zip seems permanently stuck though.

Comment: Look at what Maximus said. Try exploring that route and see if that fixes it.